# i have created a check box dynamicaly want to validate the checkbox before submiting form

Tags: javascript

A checkbox will be created according to the query. I want to validate the checkbox before submitting the form.

I have used that check all and uncheck all using javascript so I used the attribute `id` in an array:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="playlist[]" id="playlist" value="<?php echo $filmpath; ?>"/>
```

I used the validation code as

```
 //enter code here
 function chkvalidate()
 {
   //enter code here
   if ( document.modifyform.playlist.checked == false )
   {
     //enter code here
     alert( "Please check the Terms & Conditions box." );
     //enter code here
     valid = false;
     //enter code here
   }
 }
```

This code is not working.

Comment: Why isnt it working? What error messages do you get?

Comment: Did you try a debug? Or else can you add a try..catch and alert the error. This will help you understand the issue.

Comment: I am not getting any error i gave the alert mgs to that function but that function is not working

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct capitalisation in your code? JavaScript is case sensitive, and I believe that if you change `modifyform` to `modifyForm` your code will likely execute properly.

That being said, it is a good idea to use camelCase as a naming convention for your variable and function names. It is not required, but it makes for more consistent and easier to read code. Additionally, since any respectable third party library will be using camelCase, it will make it much easier for yourself if you use that convention as well, *otherwise you will have multiple naming conventions throughout your source code, and that is simply not maintainable*.

Answer (score 0):

You need `document.forms.modifyform.playlist.checked` instead to access the form (by name or id) in the DOM. With your existing code, Javascript is trying to access a property called `modifyform` on the [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document) object, which does not exist.

For reference, [`documentation.form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form) shows the list of properties you can call on the `form` object.

Comment: There is a plugin (the name of which escapes me) which adds the `modifyForm` property to the `document.forms` object. This is why I was under the belief @Akila spelled it wrong, because the property the plugin creates is spelled: `modifyForm`. However, if Akila is not using this plugin (or perhaps fails to include the plugin code before the actual code), then yes, there will be no modifyform object.